# Effect size for rectangular frequency table

Tags: chi-squared-test, contingency-tables, effect-size

I have run several Chi-square tests and want a measure of effect size. I have some 1x2 tables, 1x4 tables, 4x9, and 3x4  tables of frequency data.

What measure of effect size can I use on these rectangular frequency tables, if each cell has a different expected frequency?

(I would like to use something like Cramer's V, but it only applies to tables with the same expected frequencies.)

Sample data: two groups, 'false' observes 535 (expected: 3/4), 'true' observes 222 (expected: 1/4).

Comment: I think you're wrong about Cramer's $V$ requiring equal expected frequencies...Do you have a source to support your claim? I can't find any myself, and the formula certainly doesn't require equal frequencies to produce a result.

Answer (score 4):

Actually Cramer's *V* will work for non-square tables.  See [Measures of Association](http://www.harding.edu/sbreezeel/460%20Files/Statbook/chapter15.pdf)
or
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V)

Comment: My fault. I meant that it does not work for non-square tables with different expected frequencies. I have edited the original question.